# No Output from a Shell using a Python program

Tags: python, shell

Hello I wrote a Quicksort program which is getting text files as Input. My problem starts when I use a Shell and want to run the program. I'm not getting an Output or any Error Code. I tried everything but I can't to make my code work.

```py
import sys

testfile = open(sys.argv[len(sys.argv)-1]
array = testfile.readline()

def Quick_Sort(array, first= 0, last=len(array)-1):
    
    def Partition(array, anf, last):
        Pivot_index = anf
        Pivot = array[Pivot_index]
    
        while anf < last:
            while anf < len(array) and array[anf] <= Pivot:
                anf += 1
            
            while array[last] > Pivot:
                last -= 1
            
            if anf < last:
                array[anf], array[last] = array[last], array[anf]
            
        array[last], array[Pivot_index] = array[Pivot_index], array[last]
        
        return last

    if first < last:
        
        p = Partition(array, first, last)
        
        Quick_Sort(array, first, p-1)
        Quick_Sort(array, p+1, last)
    
    return(array)

Quick_Sort(array)
```

I stored the text files in a folder "test1" and my program in a folder "py" with an info.txt file, which contains the run command (in my case Run: python quick1.py). Like this

[image: Example]

[image: Example2]

[image: Example3]

Now when I use a Shell(in my case PuTTy) and do the following:
[image]

I don't get an Output. I am really lost and I don't know where I did something wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: You never `print()` anything or write anything to a file. What output do you expect?

Comment: To get an output in the terminal, you would need to write it using the `print` statement. Assuming there are no other errors and you want to show the `array` returned by your program in the terminal,  In the end, try `print (Quick_Sort(array))` instead of just `Quick_Sort(array)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what output have you expected? Since you didn't print() anything the program had executed itself and it didn't return any problem. You sorted (I assume you did, I didn't check whether it is good algorithm or not) the list and that's all.

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel stupid to not notice this. You saved my day

Comment: @Akule8 np mate, I have similar problems everyday